# Missing column header when adding new column to Wicket DefaultDataTable

Tags: wicket

My goal is to add new columns to an existing DefaultDataTable by pressing a button. I can add columns to the table (without pressing any button) this way

```
columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model<String>("First Name"), "name.first"));
```

and everything works fine. The table looks like this

```
First Name   Last Name
----------   ---------
Novak        Djokovic
Rafael       Nadal
David        Ferrer
```

The problem comes when I try to add a new column by pressing a button. The desired result would be this

```
First Name   Last Name   Nick Name
----------   ---------   ---------
Novak        Djokovic    Nole
Rafael       Nadal       Rafa
David        Ferrer      Ferru
```

but I get this

```
First Name   Last Name
----------   ---------
Novak        Djokovic    Nole
Rafael       Nadal       Rafa
David        Ferrer      Ferru
```

As you can see, the new column header doesn't appear, and I need it to be shown. Here you have the html

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd">
    <head>
        <title>DataTable Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form wicket:id="form">
            <input wicket:id="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
        <table wicket:id="datatable"></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the code:

```
public class DataTablePage {        

    final UserProvider userProvider = new UserProvider();
    DefaultDataTable table;
    List<IColumn<?>> columns = new ArrayList<IColumn<?>>();

    public DataTablePage() {
        columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model<String>("First Name"), "name.first"));
        columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model<String>("Last Name"), "name.last"));

        table = new DefaultDataTable("datatable", columns, userProvider, 10);
        table.setOutputMarkupId(true).setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        add(table);

        Form form = new Form("form");       
        add(form);

        form.add(new AjaxButton("submit") {
             @Override
             protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {          
                 columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model<String>("Nick Name"), "name.nick"));              
                 if (target != null)
                     target.add(table);                      
             }          
             @Override
             protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {}
        });             
    }

    public class UserProvider extends SortableDataProvider {
        private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

        public UserProvider() {
            contacts.add(new Contact(new Name("Novak", "Djokovic", "Nole")));
            contacts.add(new Contact(new Name("Rafael", "Nadal", "Rafa")));
            contacts.add(new Contact(new Name("David", "Ferrer", "Ferru")));
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator iterator(int first, int count) {
            return contacts.subList(first, first + count).iterator();
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return contacts.size();
        }

        public IModel<Contact> model(final Object object) {
            return new AbstractReadOnlyModel<Contact>() {
                @Override
                public Contact getObject() {
                    return (Contact) object;
                }
            };
        }
    }

    class Name implements Serializable {    
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String nickName;

        // Constructor, getters and setters
    }

    class Contact implements Serializable {     
        private final Name name;

        // Constructor and getter
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is improved in Wicket 6 - see WICKET-4596.